# Paypal subscription button in php

Tags: php, paypal

Hello i m trying to create a paypal subscription button after payment complete paypal will return in my success page with the array bellow

```
Array
(
 [auth] => A6nD0MjozNYLgA-A05px8rNLr3mKg-gdRPEpu2VMo8jcPB9D0gh5TCuVnVcvBqNZBL1gS1S6AqBXXc8Wqmay9FdH2wFAn-hll26PXuHWv8nQ
 [rapidsState] => MerchantPayments__Subscription__StandardSubscriptionsFlow___StateDone
 [rapidsStateSignature] => 6a1cdb1820bfbb59264d5a2869ad09c618034678
 [form_charset] => UTF-8
 [PHPSESSID] => 4mcc95213nh89nep170dbs1235
)
```

but there is no information which subscription has been done means the payment. how would i know which subscription has been done. i can't tracking that amount plz help me about it anyone. I m using php language

Comment: How do you send the user to PayPal? https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough details as to which paypal you are using. Try to use braintree [here](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/) or you still use paypal rest api directly [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/directory/#paypal-rest-solutions-and-apis)